# TsLint ignore files or don't run when opening file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, web-essentials

I have Visual Studio 2013 (update 2) with Web Essentials 2013.

Every time I open files like lib.d.ts, TsLint starts to run and takes a long time to then finally spam my messages full. I don't want any messages telling me to fix stuff in files that aren't mine.

Is it possible to exclude these files? Or at least stop TsLint from running every time I open a file? Or tell TsLint not to run on files that aren't in my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next time you open a file you don't want tslint  to process add the following to the top:

```
/* tslint:disable */
```

This will disable linting for that file.

Comment: I thought that would work, it worked with the three.d.ts file, but not with the lib.d.ts. It still gives about 300-600 messages, all complaining about missing semicolons. What's going on here?

Comment: `lib.d.ts` is slightly special in that it ships with tsc. Is it the `lib.d.ts` found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0`?

Comment: The full path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.d.ts

Comment: Okay. So there might be two lib.d.ts files. One in VS one in TS SDK. Update both. Also it might be shipping with web essentials that's need to be modified.